# An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server

Tags: mongodb

I've encountered this from time to time and I cant seem to find the fix.

Usually when this error occur, I am seeing increasing number of connections being used while its connection is not being disconnected.

Here is a sample logs on mongo.
[image: Here is the sample below]

But I observed that this log below is its normal behaviour:
[image]

Another thing that I noticed before the error occur is that there are numerous "Unable to gather storage statistics for a slow operation due to lock aquire timeout"[image]

At the first time I encountered this issue. We set MaxConnectionPoolSize = 200; then it occurred again. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a locking problem. You should open profiler and watch which queries are locking each other.

Otherwise may be you can try it after researches.

[Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/index.html#param.maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis).

```
db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis: 200 } )
```